# Getting warnings in opencv when using VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

When I run this code to play a video using cv2

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get gstreamer warnings. I have tried this on two computers:

```
(python:4145): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GstObject'

(python:4145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion '((GObject *) object)->ref_count > 0' failed

(python:4145): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GstObject'

(python:4145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion '((GObject *) object)->ref_count > 0' failed

(python:4145): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GstObject'

(python:4145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: assertion '((GObject *) object)->ref_count > 0' failed

(python:4145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object->refcount > 0' failed

(python:4145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object->refcount > 0' failed
```

I have tried updating gstreamer, installing plugins but nothing seems to work. How can I get rid of the warnings.